# Make only last line editable in ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

Ace editor
read only region required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `exec` event on `editor.commands` to disable non readonly commands if wrong lines are selected

```css
body,html {
    height: 90%
}
```

```html
<script src=https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js></script>
<script>
editor = ace.edit(document.body)
editor.setOptions({
  mode: "ace/mode/javascript"
});
editor.commands.on("exec", function(e) {
    if (e.command.readOnly)
        return;
    var editableRow = editor.session.getLength() - 1;
    var deletesLeft = e.command.name == "backspace" || e.command.name == "removewordleft";
    debugger
    var notEditable = editor.selection.getAllRanges().some(function(r) {
        if (deletesLeft && r.start.column == 0 && r.end.column == 0) return true;
        return r.start.row != editableRow || r.end.row != editableRow;
    });
    if (notEditable)
        e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did actually work. However, when I use backspace, I am able to delete previous lines as well. 
Basically, I want a terminal like feel with some prompt in each line using ace editor

Comment: should it be possible for selection go to previous lines at all? if no, you may be able to use the repl implementation from cloud9 https://github.com/c9/core/blob/master/plugins/c9.ide.ace.replrepl.js

Comment: we can go to previous lines, but we can't edit them. 
Only current line should be editable.

Comment: updated the snippet to disable backspace at the line start. This probably needs to also change the appearance of cursor and line highlight on non editable lines to not be confusing to the user. Moving selection to the editable line after preventDefault call may be useful as well.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!